# How to push with Mercurial as two different users?

Tags: mercurial, bitbucket

I have two users on BitBucket, linked to two different repositories (work and private). How do I make sure that when I push to a repository, the push will be attributed to the right user?

I've tried adding two `username`s under `[ui]` in my `~/.hgrc` file, but that didn't do what I was hoping for..

Answer (score 1):

Read about [[auth] section in .hgrc](https://www.selenic.com/mercurial/hgrc.5.html#auth) and use it in your repository's file. Note from sample format of `prefix` key (it's important for different authorization credentials on the same host) for `foo` name

Comment: Thanks, but I'm using SSH, not HTTP. Is there a suitable option for that too?

Comment: @shakedzy - and your OS is...?

Comment: Using Linux (Ubuntu 16.04)

Comment: @shakedzy - http://dbushell.com/2013/01/27/multiple-accounts-and-ssh-keys/ will help

Comment: Unless I'm missing something, the above link explains how to use two different accounts, not what I was asking.

Comment: @shakedzy - in the context of SSH with public-key auth, 2 accounts = 2 different keys, thus - hints are applicable